# Escaping pattern letters and providing fixed letters in <p:calendar pattern>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to include word in the primefaces pattern and I need to escape that word which is not meant to change, like: "01.00AM", because if it's not escaped instead of printing current date like "2013/09/19 01.00AM" it prints "2013/09/19 01.00A9".

```
<p:calendar pattern="yyyy/MM/dd 01.00AM"/>
```

How can I escape key pattern letters?

Answer (score 0):

[`<p:calendar>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/calendar.html) uses a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) pattern to format the date instance in its `pattern` attribute.

To quote the relevant part of the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class that extends the abstract base class:

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings. Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote. All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting or matched against the input string during parsing.

we have that you can use the following notation to achieve what you want:

```
pattern="yyyy/MM/dd 01.00'AM'"
```

That said, if you want to use the Am/pm marker in your pattern (with the time in AM/PM format from the date instance), just use `a` where you want that output:

```
pattern="yyyy/MM/dd K:mm a"
```

Comment: Theoretically, you're right (apart from the wrong placement of the first singlequote, OP also wanted to have `01:00` fixed). But have you actually tested it in practice? Look like not. Here, PrimeFaces JavaScript fails with *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier*.

Comment: Yep, that's a misplacement! Unfortunately, I haven't been able to test it, but in case PrimeFaces fails to work with this (straightforward) solution can only mean that PF doesn't rely on `SimpleDateFormat` implementation, but rather on an extension of `DateFormat` of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Skunstel answer is theoretically right, but for the calendar to work you need to escape singlequotes with backslash, so, the following pattern will do it:

```
pattern="yyyy/MM/dd \'01.00AM\'"
```